# How can i convert a 22bpp gif image to a 32bpp gif image in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls, wpf-4.0

I am using picturebox control in WPF to show a Gif image. Since i am using AllowTransperency="True", picturebox control is not getting displayed. As per this [stackoverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22389750/cotrols-in-winformhost-does-not-shown-when-windows-allowtransparency-true) i have to convert my 22bpp image to 32bppimage. How can i do that? Kindly advice.

```
<Window Loaded="Window_Loaded" VeritcalAlignment="Center" AllowTransperency="True" Background="Transparent">

<border Background="Transpernt" BorderThickness="0">

<Grid>
<wfi:WindowsFormsHost Grid.Row="4" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">

<winForms:PictureBox x:Name="myImage"></winForms:PictureBox>                  </wfi:WindowsFormsHost>
```

Code Behind

```
myImage.Image = @"C:\MyImage.Gif";
```

Please help. Thanks a lot for your help and time in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [GifBitmapEncoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.gifbitmapencoder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). One solution would be iterate over each frame and convert each bitmap.

Also, take a look at [NGif](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11505/NGif-Animated-GIF-Encoder-for-NET), an open source library. It may suit you needs more.